# flyspell correct the previous to previous mistake

Tags: emacs, flyspell

suppose I have buffer contents as follows

```
teh msot |
```

curser is at `|`. generally I can correct `msot` to `most` with single `C-;` press (flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word). What I want is to correct `teh` to `the`, i.e previous to previous mistake. (or in general nth spell)

It seems `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word` is taking numerical argument but not yielding intended result.

what am I missing.?

UPDATE:

Why I need this., when I write research notes, flyspell mistakenly marks some scientific words wrong. So need to skip the one or two false marks.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to have the mark set at the corrected word, so that popping the mark and executing another another <kbd>C-;</kbd> would correct the word? The variable `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-pos` holds the position of the start of the first incorrect word before point. Or, are you specifically looking to skip the immediately previous word altogether?

Comment: Hmm, looking at the source of `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word`, there isn't an obvious way to do this. It works by walking through `overlays-in` between the window start and end. You'd have to duplicate part of this behavior; a big pain. I'll take a crack at it later.

Answer (score 1):

C-h f flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word tells me that the numerical argument is called "position". That does not look like what you are looking for. Position is likely to refer to a position in the buffer. Looking at the flyspell sourcecode reveals that the parameter *is not used in the intendet way* (cant tell what an overlay is thoug...)

```
;*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
;*    flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word ...                          */
;*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
(defun flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word (position) 
  "*Auto correct the first mispelled word that occurs before point."
  (interactive "d")

  (add-hook 'pre-command-hook 
        (function flyspell-auto-correct-previous-hook) t t)

  (save-excursion
    (unless flyspell-auto-correct-previous-pos
      ;; only reset if a new overlay exists
      (setq flyspell-auto-correct-previous-pos nil)

      (let ((overlay-list (overlays-in (point-min) position))
        (new-overlay 'dummy-value))
[SNIP]
```

also the (interactive "d") shows that the current position of point is assigned to position in case of an interactive call.
matthias

Comment: Hmm.. I did go to the source.. all it is doing is go to point min with narrowed down cycle though the wrong words (using flyspell-overlay-p) stopping at last one and trying to correct. I though some one have better logic to implement a function.

Comment: @kindahero I am hardly able to discuss the pros and cons of one approach against the other, but what measures are necessary to do it another way? maintaining a list of "misspelled words" that can change at any keystroke seems to be a little overheadish, eh especially if the list grows over time. also i dont see where you are going. is your question answered? are you just ranting about flyspell?